# Is it possible to independently control volume for sound effects and music?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I want to be able to hear if a shiny has appeared but prefer my own music collection to that played during game play.

Comment: No, you cannot change the default music/sound effects.

Comment: :'( Need to complain to Game Freak then. This is just unacceptable.

Comment: Well, it's been like that since 1996 ^^ Plus if you the colour palette of a Pokemon, you'll easily spot a shiny.

Comment: I have not played much of the series. I could understand the originals not having the option but by now it should be a basic feature.

Comment: Tbh, I don't know of any game that allows you to change sound effects/music (except from mono to stereo and vice versa and some exception games where that is restricted to a particular area). A change like that would be really drastic imo.

Comment: I have not played handheld for some time, but it should be possible and should not be that big a deal surely.

Comment: To my knowledge no 3DS game has this ability. The most I've seen is being able to switch between Japanese and English audio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have stated, it is not possible to individually adjust Sound Effects & Music volume in Pokemon X/Y. Even the Mono/Stereo option has been removed in this version.

On shiny catching however, as a general rule of thumb, if you're not 100% sure if it's shiny, catch it! It's only going to cost you a Quick Ball/Pokeball to check.

You can also view the Colour differences online, [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Main_Page) lists them all on the specific Pokemon's page, for example, here is [Haunter's](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Haunter_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29#Sprites)

Comment: I just happenned to have Haunter's Bulbapedia entry open in another tab, not that I'm favouring it or anything :P

Comment: But I is lazy and the internet is just a foot or so out of reach. *Dangles arms out stretched demonstrating the distance*

Comment: Even then, I didn't find the setting to change the sound setting from mono to stereo (and vice versa). Seems they removed it in this game...

Comment: @Jerry - Huh, so it is. I'd thought I'd seen it earlier, but apparently not :)

Comment: You should! +1 for Haunter :)